# Calculating the joint probability density $e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: integration, statistics

I do not understand as to why the joint probability density of $e^{-(x+y)}$ for $x>0, y>0$ when $P(X+Y >3)$,  has the following integral bounds $\int_2^3\int_2^3dxdy$

When I sketch the region:
[image]

I cannot seem to locate how the lower bounds are 2. How should I interpret regions that involve exponentials?

Comment: Those bounds are not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe I might have made a mistake with the pdf. I have updated it

Comment: I seem to have found someone with the same post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991252/limits-of-integration-joint-probability-density?rq=1
Turns out to be an error in the book ...

Comment: Yes definitely an error in the book